# Rails: Multiple relationships between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm creating a Database Migration in Rails 4.0.4, and I want to capture the following relationship:

> A customer has many credit cards. A customer has only one default credit card.

and here's what I think it should look like.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  has_one :card # i.e. has one default card
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Is this correct? If so, how does Rails know which relationship the `belongs_to` in the `Card` class refers to? If it's incorrect (and I'm guessing it is), please help me fix it.

Comment: In your case I will go with `has_many :cards` and making a `boolean column` something like `is_default` in the `cards` table.Default cards will be having `is_default` column `true`.

Comment: Or you can do like this `has_one :default_card, :class_name => "Card"`

Comment: I also would suggest the same answer as @Pavan, and for simplicity you can define a scope for the default card, this way you'll only need 1 relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put the scope on the card's side, seems easier for me

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :card
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  scope :default, -> { where is_default: true }
end

default_card = customer.cards.default
```

Comment: In my opinion this process is a better choice than to have multiple associations with the same model. More robust and easy to maintain

Comment: @PamioSolanky I agree. Clean!

Comment: Only downside is adding an `is_default` field to the `Cards` table, which would need additional implementation logic to maintain just 1 default card / customer

Comment: So I'm trying to implement the `check_single_default_card` method that checks to make sure that there's just one card set as default (it has a `before_save` trigger in the `Card` model). How do I access the `Customer` it belongs to from the `Card` model?

Answer (score 2):

Currently your code is enough to confuse Rails by having `has_one :card` and `has_many :cards`.You should be using `class_name` option provided specially for these type of associations.

Something like this should work for you

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  has_one :default_card, :class_name => "Card"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I need to add anything on the `Card` model too?

Comment: @Yazin No,this would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

**foreign_key**

To add to `Pavan's` answer, you'll need to use some sort of condition to determine which is the `default` card.

Because Rails' [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) structure relies on [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to pull the related data, you'll need to either assign the correct `foreign_key` for your `default_card`, or use a condition to find it:

```
#app/models/customer.rb
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :default_card, -> { where default: true" },class: "Card", foreign_key: "customer_id"
end
```

This would rely on having the boolean column `default` in your `cards` table